# Build a single JSON value from two jsonb columns in two different tables

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, json

I have two tables. Both have a `jsonb` column with an array of objects, each containing the key `student_id`.

I am trying to build ***one*** aggregated JSON value from these jsonb columns.

Lets say **table A** has four rows and each has `jsonb` data like:

```
[
  {
    "student_id: 1,
    "others element from table A" ...
    ...
  },
  {
    "student_id: 2,
    "others element from table A" ...
    ...
  }
...
]
```

And **table B** has holds `jsonb` values of the form:

```
[
  {
    "student_id": 1,
    "others element from table B" ...
  },
  {
    "student_id": 2,
    "others element from table B" ...
  }
...
]
```

There is only one row from table B at a time that is to be mapped to multiple rows from table A, all containing different `"other_elements"` but with the same `"student_id"` value for each object.

My expect result is of the form:

```
[
  {
    "student_id": 1,
    "others elements from table A" ...
    "others elements from table B" ...
  },
  {
    "student_id": 2,
    "others elements from table A" ...
    "others elements from table B" ...
  }
]
```

Here is a [fiddle with sample data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6c7799d293d20f869db4d006c736edcc) demonstrating my case.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(student) AS students
FROM (
   SELECT jsonb_object_agg((kv).key, (kv).value) AS student
   FROM (
      SELECT ass->>'student_id' AS student_id, "char" 'a' AS tbl, id, jsonb_each(ass) AS kv
      FROM (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(assessment       ) AS ass, id FROM assessment) a

      UNION ALL
      SELECT ass->>'student_id'              ,        'b'       , id, jsonb_each(ass)
      FROM (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(others_assessment) AS ass, id FROM result    ) r
      ORDER BY student_id, tbl, id
      ) sub1
   GROUP  BY student_id
-- ORDER  BY student_id  -- to be explicit
   ) sub2
;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=32989e9bfb2b42fc2b14aeadc1051fcd)*

In the inner subquery **`sub1`**, for each involved table, unnest the top-level JSON array into its element objects with [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE), and then expand these objects into into a set of key/value pairs. Then `UNION ALL` all of them together and (optionally) order rows, as the order bears significance in the next step.
Note how [`jsonb_each()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) is called *once*, returning two fields, which we carry over as one composite type `kv` - with well-known fields `key` and `value`  defined by the function.

In the next subquery **`sub2`**, aggregate per `student_id` to unite all attributes with [`jsonb_object_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE). Values from later rows overrule earlier rows in case of key conflicts.
Fields of the composite type are accessed with `(kv).key, (kv).value`. This way, the function is only executed once (not once per field). Alternatively use `LATERAL` subqueries ... See:

- [How to avoid multiple function evals with the (func()).* syntax in an SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18370271/939860)

In the **outer** `SELECT`, aggregate all students into a `jsonb` array with [`jsonb_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE). Voilá.
(`ORDER BY student_id` is carried over from the inner subselect, but add it if you want to be explicit.